# How to output result of Javascript execution to console?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java, javascript

I was wondering if anyone could help me find a way to output to the Eclipse console the results returned from executing a Javascript ?

These are the steps I manually perform (that I would like to automate):

1. Open test web page.
2. Open Google chrome Javascript console
3. Type "productObj.mainURL" and enter

This will output to the Chrome Javascript console the URL value/attribute that I'm looking for.

I've done a fair bit of research on my own, and I am stumped.

I've tried the code below:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String mainURL = (String) js.executeScript("productObj.mainURL");
System.out.println(mainURL);
```

But all I get returned is a "null"...

Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell it to return the value.

Change this line:

```
String mainURL = (String) js.executeScript("productObj.mainURL");
```

to:

```
String mainURL = (String) js.executeScript("return productObj.mainURL");
```

Answer (score 1):

String mainURL = (String) js.executeScript("return productObj.mainURL"); 
will give errors for some String.

String mainURL = js.executeScript("return productObj.mainURL").toString();
is better I guess.